# Protected tag in DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

```
P[r[t_]] := -42/(r[t] + 1);
m1 := 2;
r10 := {10, 1, 0} ;
v10 := {1, 1, 0} ;
m2 := 3;
r20 := {2, 0, 0} ;
v20 := {0, 4, 0} ;
```

DSolve[
 {r''[t] (m1*m2)/(m1 + m2) == -P[r[t]],
  r[0] == r20 - r10,
  r'[0] == v20 - v10
  }, r[t], t
 ]

What's the problem? Should vector P have a dual relationship[r_,t_], if r[t_]?

Comment: Seems this hasn't been done: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is?  I do not get a protected tag error.  From the accepted answer it appears that the problem is a problem in mathematics and physics that is not explained at all in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to your specific problem, you can either modify the first line to be `P[r_] := -42/(r + 1);` or modify your differential equation `-P[r]`

Additionally, you shouldn't use `SetDelayed` `:=` to assign values to variables, instead, you should use `Set` `=`

If you are doing a two body problem, the potential does not seem to be correct, it should not have `-1`in its denominator. You can refer to http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/Two-BodyProblem.html. When you obtain the correct differential equation, you should get $m\boldsymbol{\ddot{r}}=\boldsymbol{\hat{r}} f(r)$. You should solve this differential equation coordinate-wise, but it is obvious that using polar coordinate is more convenient, by setting the centre of mass at the origin. So use the identity $\ddot{\boldsymbol{r}}=(\ddot{r}-r \ddot{\theta})\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}+(2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}+r\ddot{\theta})\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$, you can obtain two differential equations. At this point, solving the equation of the orbit would lead to an ellipse. However, it seems that you want to obtain the $\boldsymbol{r}$ with respect to time. And *Mathematica* is not able to solve

```
DSolve[{
    -r[t] Derivative[1][θ][t]^2 + r''[t] == -(k/(m r[t]^2)), 
    2 Derivative[1][r][t] Derivative[1][θ][t] + r[t] θ''[t] == 0}, 
  {r[t], θ[t]}, t]
```

So, I suggest you to transform your initial condition from cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates and use `NDSolve`to solve your problem.

It seems that it is impossible to obtain what you want. See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/171486/how-to-solve-the-inverse-square-law-equation-of-motion

Comment: Thank U. Yes, this two-body problem. It is necessary to solve coordinate-wise?
Yes, it's right. I just found 
rC0 = (m1 r10 + m2 r20)/(m1 + m2);
vC0 = (m1 v10 + m2 v20)/(m1 + m2);

Comment: I understand everything. Now I can find each coordinate vectors r1 and r2. You really helped, thank you! r1=rC-rm2/(m1+m2);r2=rC+rm2/(m1+m2)
I'll have 6 equations, right?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. m1, sure, I am confused by the equation z[t]->0 it's normal?

Comment: Then I can continue to be used only by the equation x and y?

Comment: you are always right! No more questions, thank you very much for your help.